# Passing results from Laravel 5.2 to view using AngularJS does not work correctly

Tags: angularjs

I am learning how to intergrate Angular in my Laravel app. But when I select values from a database table its displayed in the browser in Json format like shown:

```
[{"id":1,"product_name":"smart phone"},
[{"id":2,"product_name":"laptop"},
[{"id":3,"product_name":"desktop"},
[{"id":4,"product_name":"tablet"}]
```

I want my result in the view to look as so:
**id  product Name**
1    Smart Phone
2    Laptop
3    Desktop
4    tablet

My productsController.php listProducts()

```
 //List all products
   public function listProducts($id = null) {
        if ($id == null) {
            return Product::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
        } else {
            return $this->show($id);
        }

    }
```

My show products method:

```
 public function show($id) 
       {

        return Product::find($id);

    }
```

my routes.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {   
Route::get('/v1/products/{id?}' ,['as'=>'productindex','uses'=>'ProductsController@listProducts']);
Route::post('/v1/products', 'ProductsController@store');
Route::post('/v1/products/{id}', 'ProductsController@update');
Route::post('/v1/products/update/{id}',['as'=>'update','uses'=> 'ProductsController@update']);
Route::delete('/v1/products/{id}', 'ProductsController@destroy');
});
```

My productsController.js

```
//public/app/controllers/productsController.js
app.controller('productsController', function($scope, $http, API_URL) {
    //retrieve products listing from API
    $http.get(API_URL + "products")
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.products = response;
            });

    //show modal form
    $scope.toggle = function(modalstate, id) {
        $scope.modalstate = modalstate;

        switch (modalstate) {
            case 'add':
                $scope.form_title = "Add New Product";
                break;
            case 'edit':
                $scope.form_title = "Product Detail";
                $scope.id = id;
                $http.get(API_URL + 'products/' + id)
                        .success(function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            $scope.product = response;
                        });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        console.log(id);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

    //save new record / update existing record
    $scope.save = function(modalstate, id) {
        var url = API_URL + "products";

        //append employee id to the URL if the form is in edit mode
        if (modalstate === 'edit'){
            url += "/" + id;
        }

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $.param($scope.Product),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            location.reload();
        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('This is embarassing. An error has occured. Please check the log for details');
        });
    }

    //delete record
    $scope.confirmDelete = function(id) {
        var isConfirmDelete = confirm('Are you sure you want this record?');
        if (isConfirmDelete) {
            $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: API_URL + 'products/' + id
            }).
                    success(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        location.reload();
                    }).
                    error(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert('Unable to delete');
                    });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

My app.js

```
//public/app/app.js
var app = angular.module('products', [])
        .constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost/myapp/public/api/v1/');
```

my view

```
// resources/views/products/listproducts.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="products">
    <head>
        <title>Laravel 5 AngularJS CRUD Example</title>

        <!-- Load Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="<?= asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Employees Database</h2>
        <div  ng-controller="productsController">

            <!-- Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                     <th>Product Id</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>



                        <th><button id="btn-add" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="toggle('add', 0)">Add New Product</button></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
                        <td>{{  product.proudct_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{  product.product_name }}</td>                               

                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-detail" ng-click="toggle('edit', product.id)">Edit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete" ng-click="confirmDelete(product.id)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- End of Table-to-load-the-data Part -->
            <!-- Modal (Pop up when detail button clicked) -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{form_title}}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form name="frmEmployees" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">

                                <div class="form-group error">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Fullname" value="{{name}}" 
                                        ng-model="employee.name" ng-required="true">
                                        <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmEmployees.name.$invalid && frmEmployees.name.$touched">Name field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="{{email}}" 
                                        ng-model="employee.email" ng-required="true">
                                        <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmEmployees.email.$invalid && frmEmployees.email.$touched">Valid Email field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact Number</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Contact Number" value="{{contact_number}}" 
                                        ng-model="employee.contact_number" ng-required="true">
                                    <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmEmployees.contact_number.$invalid && frmEmployees.contact_number.$touched">Contact number field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Position</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" name="position" placeholder="Position" value="{{position}}" 
                                        ng-model="employee.position" ng-required="true">
                                    <span class="help-inline" 
                                        ng-show="frmEmployees.position.$invalid && frmEmployees.position.$touched">Position field is required</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" ng-click="save(modalstate, id)" ng-disabled="frmEmployees.$invalid">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Load Javascript Libraries (AngularJS, JQuery, Bootstrap) -->
        <script src="<?= asset('app/lib/angular/angular.min.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?= asset('js/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?= asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') ?>"></script>

        <!-- AngularJS Application Scripts -->
        <script src="<?= asset('app/app.js') ?>"></script>
        <script src="<?= asset('app/controllers/productsController.js') ?>"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is what May I doing wrong. Its like the listProducts method in productsController.php is not passing results to listproducts.php. What should I do? Kindly assist.

Comment: Did you check that endpoint responds with proper JSON?

Comment: Can you post the output of /api/v1/products?
What you have at the top is badly formatted JSON (bunch of [ and no ]). Should be [{"id":1,"product_name":"smart phone"},{"id":2,"product_name":"laptop"},{"id":3,"product_name":"desktop"},{"id":4,"product_name":"tablet"}]

Comment: I have edited the output of /api/v1/products in the beginning of the question.But the typo is not in my real output. Its like you've demonstrated it here.  thank you for pointing this out though is not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel and angular notations overlap (both blade and angular use '{{' to output variables). I had to change angular behaviour using:

```
app.config(['$interpolateProvider',
        function($interpolateProvider) {
            $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
            $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
}])
```

I guess you can do something similar on Laravel, but I don't know how. 
that problem solved, you could try and output the content of '$scope.products' in the html page, to see if it is what you expect. The response to the api call seems ok, so the problem likely lies in the angular side.

Comment: my view is not a blade template. Conflict would come about if using blade template. I just don't understand where the communication from the controller and the view is breaking